# adding li item to the list selectable using button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<ol id="selectable">

  <li class="ui-widget-content">List Item 1</li>
  
</ol>
```

How can I add a new item to the list using button add and the index will be incremented by +1 when I click the button using jQuery?

For example, when I click add, List Item 2 will be added, then click so List Item 3 will be added.

Comment: Show what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without **Jquery** how ?

- create a button and give it id **btn** to select it in javascript
- select the list by its id
- create a variable called **index** for example to track every time you click the button
- when the user click the button , increment index and create new **li** element
- set the content of the **li** and finally append it to the list

here is the complete example

```js
const selectable = document.getElementById('selectable');
const button = document.getElementById('btn');

let index = 1;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    index++;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = 'List Item ' + index;
    selectable.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Add</button>
<ol id="selectable">

  <li class="ui-widget-content">List Item 1</li>
  
</ol>
```

Comment: have an example using jquery ?

Comment: You can do it without jquery , but if you need to do it with Jquery, the algorithm is the same but you just  to select element using jquery syntax .

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use the `append` function to insert an element behind another element:

```js
$('#add').click(function(e){
  var itemid = $('#list li:last').attr('id');
  var num = parseInt(itemid.substring(4, itemid.length), 10)+1;
  $('#list li:last').append('<li id="item'+num+'">List Item '+num+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add item to list</button>
<ul id="list">
<li id="item1">List Item 1</li>
</ul>
```